# Date() showing Invalid Date

Tags: javascript, date

Here is my code .I want to convert the date value given under `div` to a date string  and create a new date under `id=demo`section from that string using `innerText`.but the `res` shows `Invalid Date`.So please help me find the error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<div>
    &nbsp;Monday,&nbsp; December&nbsp;&nbsp;22,&nbsp;2014&nbsp;|&nbsp;03:05:01 AM
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() 
 {
  DivisionHoldingTime=document.getElementsByTagName("div");
  var matches = DivisionHoldingTime[0].innerText;  
  var res = new Date (matches.trim().replace(/\|/,""));//**See Code Below
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =res;//Shows Invalid Date
 }


</script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

If I will replace this statement with this

```
 var res =new Date("Monday,  December  22, 2014 | 03:05:01 AM".trim().replace(/\|/,"")); 
// document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =res;-Shows the  Date
```

then it works fine.Then,

Why `res` shows result as `Invalid date` in first case?Please find out the error for me.

Comment: Is your problem the regular expression to match the expected date pattern (and hence find the div with a date), or with parsing the string?

Comment: No I just want to create a date string from the date above.

Comment: Downvoters who don't explain their vote are lazy. Voting to close this as "off topic" makes no sense, it's a question about using javascript to parse date strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally ,after a lots of search ,I got my problem solved.The reason for which `res` was showing `Invalid Date` is that `innerText` was unable to remove the string`&nbsp;` from the string .So when I replace the code

```
  var res = new Date (matches.trim().replace(/\|/,""));
```

with

```
  var res = new Date (matches.trim().replace(/\u00a0/g," ").replace(/\|/,""));
```

It worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the regular expression, I'd use:

```
/\w+,\s+\w+\s+\d{1,2},\s+\d{4}\s+\|\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s+[ap]m/ig;
```

The matched string should be manually parsed to generate a Date object, you can use something like:

```
// s is string in format DDD, MMM dd, dddd | hh:mm:ss ap
function parseString(s) {
  s = s.toLowerCase();
  var b = s.match(/[\w]+/g);
  var months = {january:0, february:1, march:2, april:3, may:4, june:5,
                july:6, august:7, september:8, october:9, november:10, december:11};
  return new Date(b[3], months[b[1]], b[2], ((b[7]=='am'? 0 : 12) + b[4]%12), b[5], b[6]);
}
```

So then the function becomes:

```
function myFunction() {
  var all_DivTags = document.querySelectorAll("div");
  var dateMatcherRegEx = /\w+,\s+\w+\s+\d{1,2},\s+\d{4}\s+\|\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s+[ap]m/i;

  for (i=0, iLen=all_DivTags.length; i<iLen; i++) {

    if (dateMatcherRegEx.test(all_DivTags[i].textContent)) {
      divisionHoldingTime = all_DivTags[i].textContent.match(dateMatcherRegEx)[0];
      break;
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = parseString(divisionHoldingTime);
}
```

Note that by convention, only constructors have a name starting with a capital letter (though constants may have names of all capitals).

Comment: Thanks for the code.But I want to do it in my way.Could you please find the error in my code?Why it is not working?Look at this code below `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = new Date("Monday,  December  22, 2014 | 03:05:01 AM".replace(/\|/,""));` It works fine when I am supplying string directly in the above format,but when I am using `innerText`to get the same string it is not working.Then what could be the problem?

Comment: Do not use the Date constructor to parse strings, it calls *Date.parse*, which is largely implementation dependant and notoriously unreliable (as you've discovered). Just don't do it, write your own parser for the format you expect.